# Using Alexa skill customer porofile api along with dynamodb inorder to save user email address

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a demo Alexa Skill wherein I use the Customer Profile API to get customer details such as email etc and then I want to save the email id to a dynamoDb . I have followed all the instructions from the documentation and am unable to get this to work. Please see my code and tell me what am I doing wrong. Any help or fresh perspective is appreciated.

```
    dBhelper.js

    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update({region: "us-east-1"});
    const tableName = "user-emails";

    var dbHelper = function () { };
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    dbHelper.prototype.addEmail = (email, userID) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                Item: {
                  'email' : email,
                  'userId': userID
                }
            };
            docClient.put(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Unable to insert =>", JSON.stringify(err))
                    return reject("Unable to insert");
                }
                console.log("Saved Data, ", JSON.stringify(data));
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }





    module.exports = new dbHelper();


    index.js

    //const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
    const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
    const dbHelper = require('./helpers/dbHelper');
    const GENERAL_REPROMPT = "What would you like to do?";
    const dynamoDBTableName = "user-emails";

    const messages = {
      WELCOME: 'Welcome to the Sample Alexa Customer Profile API Skill! You can ask for your name, your email address, or your phone number. What do you want to ask?',
      WHAT_DO_YOU_WANT: 'What do you want to ask?',
      NOTIFY_MISSING_PERMISSIONS: 'Please enable Customer Profile permissions in the Amazon Alexa app.',
      NAME_MISSING: 'You can set your name either in the Alexa app under calling and messaging, or you can set it at Amazon.com, under log-in and security.',
      EMAIL_MISSING: 'You can set your email at Amazon.com, under log-in and security.',
      NUMBER_MISSING: 'You can set your phone number at Amazon.com, under log-in and security.',
      NAME_AVAILABLE: 'Here is your full name: ',
      EMAIL_AVAILABLE: 'Here is your email address: ',
      NUMBER_AVAILABLE: 'Here is your phone number: ',
      ERROR: 'Uh Oh. Looks like something went wrong.',
      API_FAILURE: 'There was an error with the Alexa Customer Profile API. Please try again.',
      GOODBYE: 'Bye! Thanks for using the Sample Alexa Customer Profile API Skill!',
      UNHANDLED: 'This skill doesn\'t support that. Please ask something else.',
      HELP: 'You can use this skill by asking something like: whats my name?',
      STOP: 'Bye! Thanks for using the Sample Alexa Customer Profile API Skill!',
    };

    const PERMISSIONS = ['alexa::profile:name:read', 'alexa::profile:email:read', 'alexa::profile:mobile_number:read'];

    const LaunchRequest = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.WELCOME)
          .reprompt(messages.WHAT_DO_YOU_WANT)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const NameIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'NameIntent';
      },
      async handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;

        const consentToken = requestEnvelope.context.System.apiAccessToken;
        if (!consentToken) {
          return responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NOTIFY_MISSING_PERMISSIONS)
            .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(PERMISSIONS)
            .getResponse();
        }
        try {
          const client = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
          const name = await client.getProfileName();

          console.log('Name successfully retrieved, now responding to user.');

          let response;
          if (name == null) {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.NAME_MISSING).getResponse();
          } else {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.NAME_AVAILABLE + name).getResponse();
          }
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name !== 'ServiceError') {
            const response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.ERROR).getResponse();
            return response;
          }
          throw error;
        }
      },
    };

    const EmailIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'EmailIntent';
      },
      async handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;

        const consentToken = requestEnvelope.context.System.apiAccessToken;
        if (!consentToken) {
          return responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NOTIFY_MISSING_PERMISSIONS)
            .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(PERMISSIONS)
            .getResponse();
        }
        try {
          const client = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
          const email = await client.getProfileEmail();

          console.log('Email successfully retrieved, now responding to user.');

          let response;
          if (email == null) {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.EMAIL_MISSING).getResponse();
          } else {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.EMAIL_AVAILABLE + email).getResponse();
          }
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name !== 'ServiceError') {
            const response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.ERROR).getResponse();
            return response;
          }
          throw error;
        }
      },
    };



    const AddEmailIntentHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AddEmailIntent';
      },
      async handle(handlerInput) {
        const {responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        const userID = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.userId;
        const client = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
          const email = await client.getProfileEmail();

        return dbHelper.addEmail(email, userID)
          .then((data) => {
            const speechText = `You have added the email id.`;
            return responseBuilder
              .speak(speechText)
              .reprompt(GENERAL_REPROMPT)
              .getResponse();
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error occured while saving email", err);
            const speechText = "we cannot save your email right now. Try again!"
            return responseBuilder
              .speak(speechText)
              .getResponse();
          })
      },
    };





    const NumberIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'NumberIntent';
      },
      async handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;

        const consentToken = requestEnvelope.context.System.apiAccessToken;
        if (!consentToken) {
          return responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NOTIFY_MISSING_PERMISSIONS)
            .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(PERMISSIONS)
            .getResponse();
        }
        try {
          const client = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
          const number = await client.getProfileMobileNumber();

          console.log('Number successfully retrieved, now responding to user.');

          let response;
          if (number == null) {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.NUMBER_MISSING).getResponse();
          } else {
            response = responseBuilder.speak(`${messages.NUMBER_AVAILABLE} ${number.countryCode} ${number.phoneNumber}`).getResponse();
          }
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name !== 'ServiceError') {
            const response = responseBuilder.speak(messages.ERROR).getResponse();
            return response;
          }
          throw error;
        }
      },
    };

    const SessionEndedRequest = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
      },
    };

    const UnhandledIntent = {
      canHandle() {
        return true;
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(messages.UNHANDLED)
          .reprompt(messages.UNHANDLED)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const HelpIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(messages.HELP)
          .reprompt(messages.HELP)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const CancelIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(messages.GOODBYE)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const StopIntent = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(messages.STOP)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const ProfileError = {
      canHandle(handlerInput, error) {
        return error.name === 'ServiceError';
      },
      handle(handlerInput, error) {
        if (error.statusCode === 403) {
          return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NOTIFY_MISSING_PERMISSIONS)
            .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(PERMISSIONS)
            .getResponse();
        }
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(messages.LOCATION_FAILURE)
          .reprompt(messages.LOCATION_FAILURE)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };


    const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

    exports.handler = skillBuilder
      .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequest,
        NameIntent,
        EmailIntent,
        AddEmailIntent,
        NumberIntent,
        SessionEndedRequest,
        HelpIntent,
        CancelIntent,
        StopIntent,
        UnhandledIntent,
      )
      .addErrorHandlers(ProfileError)
      .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
      .withCustomUserAgent('cookbook/customer-profile/v1')
      .withTableName(dynamoDBTableName)
      .withAutoCreateTable(true)


      .lambda();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting?  Have you:

1. Made sure the permissions are set up to access information via
   the skills?

The code for getting device information doesn't lookcorrect for the standard skill builder.

Here is some sample code I am using to retrieve the users timezone and given name.

```
try
{
  const deviceID  = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.deviceId; 
  if (deviceID) {
    const deviceAddressServiceClient = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
    timeZone = await deviceAddressServiceClient.getSystemTimeZone(deviceID);
    givenName = await deviceAddressServiceClient.getProfileGivenName(deviceID);
  }
}
```